# DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist - chromedriver

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome

I get the error DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist when I try to open an chrome instance.
I do kill old tasks before and I also added all these options:

```
options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model
        //options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("enable-automation");
        options.addArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation");
        options.addArguments("start-maximized"); // open Browser in maximized mode
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); // disabling infobars
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); // disabling extensions
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); // applicable to windows os only
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems

        options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
```

It does not help at all. If I stick to the headless option I get an error with no such element.
I am using chrome version 72 and chromedriver 2.46 under windows 7.
Any ideas?

It works in firefox btw.